# MSVC + Union + SSE = некорректный скомпилированный код

Tags: c++, visual-c++, union, sse

Наблюдаю странное поведение компилятора MSVC. Подозреваю, что я неправильно использую `union` и нарушаю выравнивание. Компилирую 64х битным MSVC командой `cl /std:c++20 /O2 /Z7 algo.cpp`.

Имеется структура `Board` размера 40 байт и функция `print_board`. При компиляции с флагом `/O2` проблемный участок кода (помечен комментом) превращается в набор SSE инструкций, а запуск программы приводит к выводу мусора (`idx` считается неверно и выходит за границу массива). Проблема пропадает в билде без `/O2`. Так же она пропадает, если развернуть цикл как написанно в закомменченных строчках (работает корректно даже с `/O2`, причём компилятор генерирует вообще другой код вроде бы без SSE и инлайнит всю функцию).

```
#include <cstdio>

using Bitboard = unsigned long long;
struct Board {
    union {
        struct {
            Bitboard a,b,c,d;
        };
        Bitboard bbs[4];
    };
    Bitboard occ;
};

void print_board(const Board &b) {
    constexpr char dict[] = ".ABCD";
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
        printf("%d ", i);
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; ++j) {
            int idx = 0, off = i*8+j;
            // баг проявляется здесь
            for (int k = 1; k <= 4; ++k)
                idx += k * ((b.bbs[k-1] >> off) & 1);
            /* idx = 1 * ((b.bbs[0] >> off) & 1) */
            /*     + 2 * ((b.bbs[1] >> off) & 1) */
            /*     + 3 * ((b.bbs[2] >> off) & 1) */
            /*     + 4 * ((b.bbs[3] >> off) & 1); */

            printf("%c", dict[idx]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("  01234567\n");
}

int main() {
    // Сгенерировать случайную доску с фиксированным seed. 
    Board b; 
    b.bbs[0] = 9078816779534945ull;
    b.bbs[1] = 576465150354178056ull;
    b.bbs[2] = 2523335239976686852ull;
    b.bbs[3] = 15337864866599151762ull;
    b.occ = 18446744073709551615ull;
    /* Board b = make_random_board(); */
    print_board(b);
}
```

Ожидаемый вывод, получаемый без оптимизаций или с оптимизацийми, но с развёрнутым циклом.

```
0 ADCBDAAD
1 CACDCDBB
2 CDDCDABD
3 ADCDCDAA
4 DADCDADD
5 ADBDCCAC
6 DDCDDADD
7 CCDBDCDD
  01234567
```

Вывод с флагом `/O2` и инструкциями SSE в дизассемблере.

```
0   ♠ ÄD Ä
1    Ä√♠
2 ♠Ä♠♠ÄD√Ä
3  ♠♠√♠♠
4 DADCDADD
5 ADBDCCAC
6 DDCDDADD
7 CCDBDCDD
  01234567
```

**UPD**
Дополнил код до полностью воспроизводимого примера.

Comment: покажите код `make_random_board`. Это важно для ответа.

Comment: Нужен код в таком виде, который можно скомпилировать самому и увидеть то же поведение. Почитайте про [mcve].

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Спасибо за совет! Обновил код.

Comment: @AlexGlebe Да даже если взять "мусорное" значение, проблема воспроизводится, причем на ПСС такого, похоже, нет. Кстати, даже если выбросить объединение, оставив только массив из 4 значений...

Comment: Проблема, кажется, пропадает, если взять `unsigned long long idx = 0, off = i*8+j;`... И даже при `unsigned long long idx = 0`, а `ofs` — `int`.

Comment: @Harry Да, проблема пропадает. Причём ассмеблерный листинг вроде как почти сопадает https://i.imgur.com/D8wIXcs.png

Comment: `union` ни при чем (кстати неименованные являются нестандартным расширением), достаточно `struct Board { unsigned long long bbs[4]; };`

Comment: @user7860670 Неименованный union есть в стандарте. Это неименованных структур нет.

Comment: Структуры и прочее ни при чем. Доводим до вида https://pastebin.com/E3fZjzqJ — ошибка на VC++ как в x64, так и в x86, как и в режиме С++, так и в режиме С. Забавно, что если сделать `for(k = 0; k < 4` с соответствующей заменой в вычислении — значения выпрыгивают другие. Все исправляется при полном выключении оптимизаций или при `unsigned long long idx = 0`. Кто там хорошо шарит в английском — не пошлете сообщение о баге? Еще одно забавное наблюдение: ошибки при `i<4`, но если привести `idx += k * ((int(b[k-1]) >> off) & 1);`, то ошибки будут при `i>=4`...